# Beer-Lambert law absorption by each species

Tags: physical-chemistry, optical-properties

Light travels length $l$ through a medium with $n$ independently absorbing species with extinction coefficients $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$. According to Beer-Lambert law, the amount of light absorbed is

$$1-T=1-\exp\left(-l\sum_i \alpha_i\right)=1-\prod_i\exp(-\alpha_i l)$$

How do I find the amount of light absorbed by each species? Is it

$$I_{Ai}=(1-T)\frac{1-\exp{(-\alpha_i l)}}{\sum_i {[1-\exp{(-\alpha_i l)}]}}$$

This is the only self-consistent expression I can think of but I don't know if or why it is correct.

Comment: Is it not the fractional absorption, i.e. that for species *i* divided by that for the whole sample.

Comment: @porphyrin I'm not familiar with the concept of fractional absorption. If it is $1-\exp(-\alpha_i l)$, it doesn't add up to the total absorption $1-\prod_i \exp(-\alpha_i l)$

Comment: sorry I was not clear, I meant the fraction absorbed by species *i* so $(1-\exp(-\alpha_i l))/(1-\prod_i \exp(-\alpha_i l))$

Comment: @porphyrin that still doesn't add up to $1-T$ though. And on second thought, I feel that ratio between absorption by species $i$ and total absorption should be independent of path length $l$, because incident photons don't know how far they've travelled. Does $(1-T)\alpha_i/\sum_i \alpha_i$ look reasonable? Seems weird.